# Umbraco 7: How to get content contains the current content

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I am working on the Umbraco project, I don't know how to get the data that contain the current content
For example:

I have the programs, each program will contain a list of activity (i add the activity from multiple pickers).

Program document type

```
- Name (text box)

- Description(text box)

- Activities (multiple pickers, it will show the Activities)
```

The Activities is a list view, this list view will contain a list of activity (defined below)

The activity is defined in the activity document type.

```
- Name

- Description

- ...........
```

When I have the current activity, how can I load the program that contains the current activity?

I already tried to use activity.Parent, but the result is the Activities content (because the Activities contains Activity directly).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var program = Model.Content.Site().Descendants("program").FirstOrDefault(i => i.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("activities").Any(x => x.Id == Model.Content.Id));
```

I've used Descendants above, which means Umbraco will query all nodes that are under your root node - you should normally avoid this if you can, but I don't know your site structure :)